# Date And Time Picker Custom Format Date Change

Tags: vb.net, date, datetimepicker, vb.net-2010

My DatePicker is set to custom format dd-MMM-yy

While loading the form its coming with current date.  But I would like to see the back date of 2 years and 2 months from the current date.

```
dtValidFrom.Value = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2)
dtValidFrom.Value = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)
```

But the above code is not changing anything in the date and time picker.

I suspect the Custom Format will be the issue.

Any suggestion about how to handle this?

Comment: If you use `DateTime.Now` on the second line then what you did on the first line is just ignored. You have to call `AddMonths` on the result of `AddYears`.  Your format is irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah!!! You fixed it :)  I removed the first line and changed the 2nd line to dtValidFrom.Value = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-24)

Comment: Could you please add your comment as Answer, so that I can mark your suggestion as Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be:

```
dtValidFrom.Value = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).AddMonths(-2)
```

Comment: Wow! So short and fulfilled the expectation :)